# GenericWebhookTrigger not triggering specific build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, gitbucket

I have Jenkins running normally and a pipeline with specifications below. I set the pipeline configuration to use the Generic Webhook Trigger with the same configuration as specificated in pipeline. The webhook is also configured in my gitbucket repository to only send *push* triggers. But when I test it, the response is 200 and a body response with "triggered":false.

Pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    triggers {
    GenericTrigger(
     genericVariables: [
        [key: 'ref', value: '$.ref']
     ],
     genericHeaderVariables: [
        [key: 'X-GitHub-Event', regexpFilter: '']
     ],

     causeString: 'Triggered on $ref',

     token: '123456',

     printContributedVariables: true,
     printPostContent: true,

     silentResponse: false,

     regexpFilterText: '$ref',
     regexpFilterExpression: 'refs/heads/' + 'master'
    )
  }

    stages{...
```

Response body from gitbucket webhook:

```
{"status":"ok","data":{"triggerResults":{"testePipeline":{"id":0,"regexpFilterExpression":"refs/heads/master","regexpFilterText":"","resolvedVariables":{"ref":"","x_github_event":"","x_github_event_0":""},"triggered":false,"url":""}}}}
```

Comment: You need to have a valid value under the **ref** key. At the moment this one is missing. **regexpFilterText** and **regexFilterExpression** lines are  useless. As for as I expected if the filter fails, the webhook won't get any **id** and **url**. The missing **id** and **url** will result this **"triggered": false**  state. I will write further comments or solutions if I will go further with my very similar issue. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue as above,

```json
{
  "jobs": {
    "Test": {
      "regexpFilterExpression": "(refs/heads/Dev|refs/heads/master)",
      "triggered": false,
      "resolvedVariables": {
        "ref": ""
      },
      "regexpFilterText": "",
      "id": 0,
      "url": ""
    }
  },
  "message": "Triggered jobs."
}
```

The reason was my content type was not application/json in Github. Corrected it and the build ran fine.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was on the GitLab side. With this configuration:

```
triggers {
        GenericTrigger(
            genericVariables: [
                [key: 'user_name', value: '$.user_name'],
                [key: 'checkout_sha', value: '$.checkout_sha'],
                [key: 'web_url', value: '$.project.web_url'],
                [key: 'ref', value: '$.ref'],
                [key: 'tag', value: '$.ref', regexpFilter: 'refs/tags/'],
            ],

            causeString: '$user_name pushed tag $tag to $web_url referencing $checkout_sha',

            token: 'abc123',

            printContributedVariables: true,
            printPostContent: true,

            silentResponse: false,

            regexpFilterText: '$ref',
            regexpFilterExpression: '^refs/tags/.*'
        )
    }
```

I could use the **Tag Push** webhook, if I pushed a tag from my terminal or taged on the GitLab WebUI but couldn't do the same via the test **"Tag Push"** webhook button.

It turned out this is known issue: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/issues/52556
The request header will be the same push in both cases.

Request header and part of the body after a test Push trigger:

```
Content-Type: application/json
X-Gitlab-Event: Push Hook

{
  "object_kind": "push",
  "event_name": "push",
  "before": "ab5183fcf2d4e698f1cf6228d0c1532ac7815bcc",
  "after": "3045da963cc63720c3bbc3c1217ecf2708035bfe",
  "ref": "refs/heads/master",
.
.
.
```

Request header and part of the body after a test Tag Push trigger:

```
Content-Type: application/json
X-Gitlab-Event: Tag Push Hook

{
  "object_kind": "push",
  "event_name": "push",
  "before": "ab5183fcf2d4e698f1cf6228d0c1532ac7815bcc",
  "after": "3045da963cc63720c3bbc3c1217ecf2708035bfe",
  "ref": "refs/heads/master",
.
.
.
```

I highly recommend you check the **request headers** and the **body** too.
Of course, the **"triggered": false** may come if your filters work properly. For example, if I send a regular push event, the result will be a success with a false trigger state. This is correct because the trigger worked well but your filter too.

Comment: Your solution is correct, but the problem I had required only one change on Gitbucket's side: the webhook configuration was set to send a x-www-form-urlencoded, while Jenkins awaits a JSON. Just like the requests you've shown. Thanks a lot!